# How to write a function that returns 2 if input is 1 and returns 1 if input is 2?

Tags: javascript

I just want to share this interview problem to the community so that anyone who might encounter this in the future would at least have idea on how to answer it:

Problem :

- Write a function that accepts 1 numeric parameter 1 or 2 ( No need for validation in the function ).This function must return 1 if the input is 2 and return 2 if the input is 1.
- Write at least four solutions for this problem.  That means writing four functions with different approaches.

To make the answers consistent, lets write the function in JavaScript

Happy Coding! :D

Comment: If this were my interview question, I'd rather candidates actually work it out for themselves.

Comment: Question not for SO. More fitted to ProjectCodeGolf.

Comment: Also, anyone interviewing for a job who needed to search an answer for this question does not deserve the job

Comment: This is not a good fit for puzzles & code golf IMO, not only it is too simple but it is also linked to a single programming language which is usually frowned upon there.

Comment: I agree @FabrícioMatté, however it's as close to a reasonable forum for this sort of a question. +1 for exactly my thoughts though.

Comment: @DeeKayy90 yes, you're right that this is more on-topic at code golf than here. However, in the past we used to send all "junk" questions to programmers.SE which flooded their site with very low quality posts which would eventually get closed there as well, thus reducing the usefulness of their site (there is a lot of meta talk about this). Since then, we only migrate good quality questions to other SE sites.

Comment: This question is not bad at all, well i got a new badge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use binary XOR with 3 to do this

```
function returnTwo(input) {
    return input ^ 3;
}
```

Or as [Phil suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703888/javascript-write-a-function-that-returns-2-if-input-is-1-and-returns-1-if-inpu/22703910?noredirect=1#comment34595145_22703910)

```
function returnTwo(input) {
    return ~input + 4;
}
```

Or

```
function returnTwo(input) {
    return (input * 2) % 3;
}
```

Or

```
function returnTwo(input) {
    return Math.abs(input - 3);
}
```

Or

```
function returnTwo(input) {
    return input === 1 ? 2 : 1;
}
```

Or

```
function returnTwo(input) {
    return (input - 1) ? 1 : 2;
}
```

Or

```
function returnTwo(input) {
    return input * input === input ? 2 : 1;
}
```

-- EDIT s4m0k

```
function returnTwo (input ) {
    return 3 - input;
}
```

Comment: you have 2 approaches

Comment: @s4m0k I ll be updating :)

Comment: Better hurry, the interviewer's waiting.

Comment: How about `~input + 4` :D

Comment: @Phil Thanks :) Included that in the answer.

Comment: I edited your answer and added some

Answer (score 1):

I am new to JS.

But here is the logic. Assuming variables a and b to be the two possible inputs.

```
 var a, b, input;
```

#### 1. Simple if-else

```
  if(input==a) return b; else return a;
```

#### 2. As we know the 2 probable inputs,

```
  return ((a+b)-input);
```

#### 3. Similarly,

```
   return ((a*b)/input);
```

#### 4. Play with algebra, can do many combinations with the above solutions.